# Reverse Uglified Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I am looking for way (preferably and online site) to a reverse Uglify of some javascript. The Website: http://jsbeautifier.org/ is great for minifed code, but it is does not do a great job for ugly stuff.

Comment: Would minifying the code, then beautifying it work? I'm not sure what you mean by ugly code, unfortunately.

Comment: I am talking about reversing this code that was done with this tool: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Comment: JS Beautifier does a great job with Uglified JS code. Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I don't need the answer any more, but If you put this down as answer, I will check it off, I think it will work.

Comment: Actually UglifyJS does all sorts of really nasty renaming, transforms of switches, ifs, etc. It is really is a one-way obfuscation of the code. So JS Beautifier does not help. But my solution is to join the development team, so I can get the source code!

Comment: [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) is a JavaScript parser, minifier, compressor and beautifier toolkit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is this awesome online tool, [JSNice](http://www.jsnice.org/), that makes a great job of finding names to obfuscated variables.

> We make even obfuscated JavaScript code readable.
>   We will rename variables and parameters to names that we learn from thousands of open source projects.
>   Furthermore, often we are also able to guess or infer type annotations.

Comment: Would be nice if I could do it offline in an automated fashion.

Comment: This project is no longer maintained but it still appears to be working as of this comment.

Comment: More recently I've also used general LLMs for this purpose.

Comment: Fwiw JSNice was js lame for me - "Error compiling input" 

Answer (score 6):

### Chrome dev tools ability to Pretty Print

All you need to do is to click the `{ }` icon on the bottom toolbar to activate this feature. Of course, the names will still be obfuscated (depending on what program minfied the JavaScript in the first place), but you will at least be able to set break points and debug the code.

[image: Chrome developer tools Script view - side by side - before and after prettify]

Source: Tip #2 in [this archived article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418125316/http://www.elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know).

Comment: I tried  this, but it is the same "unminify" as jsbeutifier.org, and uglyfy does really nasty things: boolean short circuits instead of if, then, else, replace all semi-colons with commas, and other ugly things that go beyond minifying.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what options you used when you uglify your code. If you just remove the line breaks, then Chrome dev tools will be able to do a great work [as sirinivas explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18408769/4575793). But if you mangle the code, then there is no way you can get the exact previous code. (in uglifying `var logngvariable = a + b;` becomes `var c=a+b;`. there is no way a tool can figure out the previous name `logngvariable` )

On the otherhand if you want an un-uglified code you may not uglify it at the first place... :)