# What is the encoding used in this code?

Tags: javascript, encryption, decode

is there a way to know what this javascript code is how I can decrypt it to show the text?

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('A f=["\\K","\\q\\u\\x\\i\\p\\1S\\F","\\o\\D\\n\\q\\j","\\n\\i\\u\\E\\j\\C","\\L","\\o\\I\\v\\o\\j\\t\\q\\u\\E","","\\1d\\y\\q\\u","\\B","\\r\\C\\k\\t\\W\\j","\\1f\\1f\\1f","\\E\\i\\j\\1z\\n\\i\\w\\i\\u\\j\\1A\\1a\\1B\\x","\\K\\x\\q\\X\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\o\\u\\q\\D\\D\\i\\j\\o\\l\\L","\\q\\u\\u\\i\\t\\1V\\2h\\1L\\1X","\\K\\J\\x\\q\\X\\L","\\1X\\B\\F\\G\\Q\\l\\e\\1l\\e\\i\\e\\C\\e\\u\\e\\y\\e\\k\\e\\D\\e\\W\\e\\1v\\e\\u\\e\\v\\e\\v\\e\\t\\e\\1a\\e\\o\\e\\o\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\1d\\e\\t\\e\\x\\e\\i\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\p\\e\\1d\\e\\r\\e\\w\\e\\k\\e\\r\\e\\E\\e\\j\\e\\q\\e\\I\\e\\w\\e\\p\\e\\n\\e\\1i\\e\\1d\\e\\1v\\e\\X\\e\\3i\\e\\x\\e\\1i\\e\\j\\e\\j\\e\\k\\e\\y\\e\\C\\e\\1M\\e\\k\\e\\1d\\e\\t\\e\\x\\e\\i\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\r\\e\\1l\\e\\o\\e\\i\\e\\X\\e\\C\\e\\1L\\e\\y\\e\\k\\e\\i\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\w\\e\\C\\e\\1Z\\e\\E\\e\\v\\e\\u\\e\\C\\e\\1l\\e\\E\\e\\C\\e\\r\\e\\v\\e\\1F\\e\\x\\e\\k\\e\\W\\e\\1v\\e\\n\\e\\1i\\e\\x\\e\\1i\\e\\y\\e\\1a\\e\\1A\\e\\D\\e\\D\\e\\2g\\e\\1S\\e\\3j\\e\\w\\e\\1B\\e\\1v\\e\\C\\e\\n\\e\\x\\e\\i\\e\\r\\e\\r\\e\\W\\e\\1v\\e\\D\\e\\i\\e\\C\\e\\D\\e\\i\\e\\1j\\e\\u\\e\\k\\e\\i\\e\\y\\e\\v\\e\\1v\\e\\X\\e\\1l\\e\\o\\e\\E\\e\\X\\e\\C\\e\\I\\e\\1F\\e\\C\\e\\2x\\e\\1V\\e\\C\\e\\1O\\e\\k\\e\\r\\e\\E\\e\\j\\e\\q\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\u\\e\\v\\e\\1d\\e\\x\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\w\\e\\E\\e\\r\\e\\t\\e\\x\\e\\i\\e\\1F\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\E\\e\\q\\e\\x\\e\\E\\e\\q\\e\\k\\e\\1j\\e\\I\\e\\x\\e\\1i\\e\\n\\e\\2j\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\n\\e\\r\\e\\r\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\1A\\e\\1d\\e\\r\\e\\n\\e\\1i\\e\\q\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\q\\e\\v\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\x\\e\\k\\e\\q\\e\\j\\e\\v\\e\\u\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\1A\\e\\1d\\e\\r\\e\\n\\e\\1i\\e\\q\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\q\\e\\v\\e\\1a\\e\\3k\\e\\E\\e\\r\\e\\E\\e\\I\\e\\x\\e\\k\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\u\\e\\y\\e\\k\\e\\D\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\x\\e\\1i\\e\\n\\e\\i\\e\\v\\e\\E\\e\\1i\\e\\q\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\u\\e\\v\\e\\v\\e\\t\\e\\1a\\e\\o\\e\\o\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\1d\\e\\t\\e\\x\\e\\i\\e\\v\\e\\k\\e\\p\\e\\1d\\e\\r\\e\\w\\e\\k\\e\\r\\e\\E\\e\\j\\e\\q\\e\\I\\e\\w\\e\\p\\e\\n\\e\\1i\\e\\1d\\l\\1g\\l\\e\\y\\e\\k\\e\\i\\e\\w\\e\\1F\\l\\P\\2i\\1D\\1p\\2W\\1n\\Q\\F\\Q\\3h\\P\\P\\1p\\1y\\1p\\1n\\2b\\1D\\1p\\F\\Q\\1C\\P\\1n\\Q\\F\\Q\\1r\\P\\P\\1p\\F\\Q\\Y\\P\\1g\\F\\Q\\V\\P\\1n\\Q\\F\\Q\\1u\\P\\P\\1p\\F\\Q\\1b\\P\\1n\\2i\\2h\\1p\\1y\\1p\\1n\\2b\\1W\\1p\\3a\\1D\\1p\\F\\Q\\Z\\P\\1n\\Q\\F\\Q\\N\\P\\P\\1n\\2b\\2U\\Q\\F\\Q\\1E\\P\\P\\Q\\F\\Q\\1T\\P\\P\\G\\F\\Q\\1z\\P\\2e\\2e\\1g\\2T\\1n\\2e\\1n","\\m","\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\m\\p\\N\\1C\\m\\p\\Z\\1r\\m\\p\\Z\\V\\m\\p\\N\\1j\\m\\p\\N\\1u\\m\\1q\\1b\\p\\v\\Z\\1r\\Y\\m\\p\\N\\1E\\m\\p\\Y\\1b\\m\\p\\N\\1z\\m\\p\\N\\1y\\m\\p\\N\\1O\\m\\p\\N\\V\\m\\p\\N\\1r\\m\\p\\N\\1T\\m\\p\\Z\\Y\\m\\p\\N\\N\\m\\p\\Y\\Y\\m\\p\\Z\\1b\\m\\p\\Y\\1O\\m\\p\\N\\Z\\m\\p\\N\\Y\\m\\p\\V\\1z\\m\\p\\V\\1j\\m\\p\\Y\\1z\\m\\p\\V\\W\\m\\p\\Z\\1E\\m\\p\\V\\1y\\m\\p\\Y\\V\\m\\p\\Y\\1y\\m\\F\\I\\u\\r\\j\\q\\y\\u\\m\\1u\\1b\\m\\p\\1r\\1r\\m\\p\\1r\\1y\\m\\p\\1C\\V\\m\\p\\V\\1A\\m\\p\\1C\\1r\\m\\p\\1r\\Y\\m\\X\\k\\t\\m\\p\\1r\\V\\m\\p\\Z\\Z\\m\\p\\V\\1E\\m\\p\\V\\N\\m\\p\\V\\1C\\m\\p\\Z\\N\\m\\q\\F\\m\\o\\i\\j\\1B\\u\\j\\i\\t\\X\\k\\n\\m\\V\\1b\\1b\\1b\\m\\1l\\q\\u\\x\\y\\1l\\m\\x\\y\\r\\I\\w\\i\\u\\j\\m\\1u\\1u\\m\\p\\N\\1A","\\F\\t\\y\\w\\1j\\C\\k\\t\\1j\\y\\x\\i","\\t\\i\\D\\n\\k\\r\\i","\\e\\1l\\3B","\\e\\v","\\E","\\K\\q\\w\\E\\B\\1l\\q\\x\\j\\C\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\C\\i\\q\\E\\C\\j\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\o\\t\\r\\G\\l","\\J\\o\\Z\\Y\\1o\\r\\J","\\J\\1l","\\1o\\C","\\1o\\r\\J","\\l\\B\\k\\n\\j\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\j\\q\\j\\n\\i\\G\\l","\\l\\J\\L","\\K\\I\\n\\B\\q\\x\\G\\l\\n\\k\\v\\i\\n\\1q\\1l\\q\\j\\C\\1q\\j\\C\\I\\w\\v\\o\\l\\L","\\1l\\t\\q\\j\\i","\\i\\u\\j\\t\\1a","\\F\\i\\i\\x","\\1D\\j","\\j\\q\\j\\n\\i","\\n\\q\\u\\1i","\\t\\i\\n","\\t\\i\\D\\n\\q\\i\\o","\\j\\1a\\D\\i","\\j\\i\\p\\j\\J\\C\\j\\w\\n","\\C\\t\\i\\F","\\k\\n\\j\\i\\t\\u\\k\\j\\i","\\I\\t\\n","\\w\\i\\x\\q\\k\\1D\\j\\C\\I\\w\\v\\u\\k\\q\\n","\\r\\y\\u\\j\\i\\u\\j","\\K\\q\\w\\E","\\o\\t\\r\\G\\l","\\l","\\o\\I\\v\\o\\j\\t","\\C\\j\\j\\D\\3s\\J\\J\\V\\1f\\v\\D\\1f\\v\\n\\y\\E\\o\\D\\y\\j\\1f\\r\\y\\w\\J\\1o\\1F\\2g\\1T\\Z\\1j\\Y\\1v\\1E\\1a\\y\\E\\J\\2T\\2U\\y\\D\\y\\1V\\2j\\V\\1b\\1W\\1B\\J\\W\\W\\W\\W\\W\\W\\W\\W\\1z\\1C\\1i\\J\\W\\1B\\1a\\2g\\X\\t\\D\\2x\\1X\\u\\1T\\J\\o\\1u\\N\\1b\\1b\\J\\D\\q\\r\\j\\I\\t\\i\\1q\\u\\y\\j\\1q\\k\\X\\k\\q\\n\\k\\v\\n\\i\\1f\\D\\u\\E","\\D\\I\\v\\n\\q\\o\\C\\i\\x","\\1M\\k\\u","\\1O\\i\\v","\\1L\\k\\t","\\W\\D\\t","\\1L\\k\\1a","\\1M\\I\\u\\i","\\1M\\I\\n\\1a","\\W\\I\\E","\\1W\\i\\D\\j","\\1S\\r\\j","\\1Z\\y\\X","\\1y\\i\\r","\\K\\n\\q\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\t\\i\\r\\i\\u\\j\\1o\\v\\y\\p\\l\\L","\\K\\x\\q\\X\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\q\\w\\k\\E\\i\\1j\\y\\u\\j\\k\\q\\u\\i\\t\\l\\L\\K\\k\\B\\C\\t\\i\\F\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\j\\k\\t\\E\\i\\j\\B\\G\\l\\1q\\j\\y\\D\\l\\L\\K\\q\\w\\E\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\n\\k\\v\\i\\n\\1q\\j\\C\\I\\w\\v\\l\\B\\o\\t\\r\\G\\l","\\l\\J\\L\\K\\J\\k\\L\\K\\J\\x\\q\\X\\L","\\K\\k\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\n\\k\\v\\i\\n\\1q\\j\\q\\j\\n\\i\\l\\B\\C\\t\\i\\F\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\j\\k\\t\\E\\i\\j\\B\\G\\l\\1q\\j\\y\\D\\l\\L","\\K\\J\\k\\L","\\1o","\\K\\x\\q\\X\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\j\\y\\i\\l\\L\\K\\k\\B\\C\\t\\i\\F\\G\\l","\\l\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\D\\y\\o\\j\\1o\\x\\k\\j\\i\\l\\L","\\B\\m\\B","\\1u\\B\\1j\\y\\w\\w\\i\\u\\j\\o","\\1u\\B\\1j\\y\\w\\w\\i\\u\\j","\\1b\\B\\1j\\y\\w\\w\\i\\u\\j\\o","\\1Z\\y\\B\\1j\\y\\w\\w\\i\\u\\j\\o","\\K\\k\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\t\\i\\r\\i\\u\\j\\1o\\r\\y\\w\\l\\B\\C\\t\\i\\F\\G\\l","\\K\\J\\k\\L\\K\\J\\x\\q\\X\\L","\\o\\I\\w\\w\\k\\t\\1a","\\n\\k\\o\\j\\1B\\u\\x\\i\\p\\1S\\F","\\K\\D\\B\\r\\n\\k\\o\\o\\G\\l\\D\\y\\o\\j\\1o\\o\\I\\w\\w\\k\\t\\1a\\l\\L","\\1f\\1f\\1f\\K\\J\\D\\L","\\K\\J\\n\\q\\L","\\K\\J\\I\\n\\L","\\o\\t\\r","\\o\\Z\\Y\\1o\\r","\\o\\1u\\N\\1b\\1b","\\k\\j\\j\\t","\\1f\\n\\k\\v\\i\\n\\1q\\j\\C\\I\\w\\v","\\t\\i\\k\\x\\1a","\\x\\i\\F\\k\\I\\n\\j\\1f\\1d\\D\\E","\\w\\1v\\x\\i\\F\\k\\I\\n\\j\\1f\\1d\\D\\E"];1k 2w(z,H){O(-1!=z[f[1]](f[0])){1H(A M=z[f[2]](f[0]),U=0;U<M[f[3]];U++){-1!=M[U][f[1]](f[4])&&(M[U]=M[U][f[5]](M[U][f[1]](f[4])+1,M[U][f[3]]))};z=M[f[7]](f[6])};1H(H=H<z[f[3]]-1?H:z[f[3]]-2;f[8]!=z[f[9]](H-1)&&-1!=z[f[1]](f[8],H);){H++};1s z=z[f[5]](0,H-1),z+f[10]}1k 3m(z){A H=R[f[11]](z),M=3l,U=f[12]+2w(H[f[13]],M)+f[14];H[f[13]]=U}3b(1k(1h,1R,T,1m,H,2a){H=1k(T){1s(T<1R?f[6]:H(2z(T/1R)))+((T=T%1R)>35?2r[f[18]](T+29):T.3Z(36))};O(!f[6][f[19]](/^/,2r)){2q(T--){2a[H(T)]=1m[T]||H(T)};1m=[1k(H){1s 2a[H]}];H=1k(){1s f[20]};T=1};2q(T--){O(1m[T]){1h=1h[f[19]](2V 3O(f[21]+H(T)+f[21],f[22]),1m[T])}};1s 1h}(f[15],1N,1N,f[17][f[2]](f[16]),0,{}));1k 3M(H,M){A z=3L;A 1x=3I;2v=f[23]+z+f[24]+1x+f[25]+H[f[19]](f[26],f[27]+z+f[28]+1x+f[29])+f[30]+M[f[19]](/"/g,f[6])+f[31]+M[f[19]](/"/g,f[6])+f[32];O(M!=f[6]){1s 2v}1J{1s f[6]}}1k 3o(H){R[f[34]](f[33]);1H(A M=0;M<2S;M++){A z=H[f[36]][f[35]][M];A 1x=z[f[38]][f[37]];A U;O(M==H[f[36]][f[35]][f[3]]){1Y};1H(A 1t=0;1t<z[f[39]][f[3]];1t++){O(z[f[39]][1t][f[40]]==f[41]&&z[f[39]][1t][f[42]]==f[43]){A 1w=z[f[39]][1t][f[38]];A 2o=z[f[39]][1t][f[44]]};O(z[f[39]][1t][f[40]]==f[45]){U=z[f[39]][1t][f[44]];1Y}};A 1G;3T{1G=z[f[3U]][f[46]]}3H(h){s=z[f[2f]][f[37]];a=s[f[1]](f[3G]);b=s[f[1]](f[3u],a);c=s[f[1]](f[3v],b+5);d=s[f[3w]](b+5,c-b-5);O(a!=-1&&b!=-1&&c!=-1&&d!=f[6]){1G=d}1J{1G=f[3p]}};A 1h=z[f[2A]][f[37]];A 3q=1h[f[5]](0,4);A 3r=1h[f[5]](5,7);A 3x=1h[f[5]](8,10);A 1c=2V 3y;1c[1]=f[2H];1c[2]=f[2N];1c[3]=f[2O];1c[4]=f[2M];1c[5]=f[2L];1c[6]=f[2I];1c[7]=f[1N];1c[8]=f[2J];1c[9]=f[2K];1c[10]=f[2u];1c[11]=f[2G];1c[12]=f[2B];R[f[34]](f[3E]);O(3F==1Q){R[f[34]](f[3D]+U+f[3C]+1G+f[31]+1x+f[30]+1x+f[3z])};R[f[34]](f[3A]+U+f[2p]+1x+f[2l]);A 1I=f[6];A 2c=0;R[f[34]](f[6]);1h=z[f[2A]][f[37]];A 1U=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];A 2C=[f[2H],f[2N],f[2O],f[2M],f[2L],f[2I],f[1N],f[2J],f[2K],f[2u],f[2G],f[2B]];A 2P=1h[f[2]](f[2d])[2][f[5]](0,2);A 1P=1h[f[2]](f[2d])[1];A 2R=1h[f[2]](f[2d])[0];1H(A 1m=0;1m<1U[f[3]];1m++){O(2z(1P)==1U[1m]){1P=2C[1m];1Y}};A 2k=2P+f[8]+1P+f[8]+2R;O(3t==1Q){R[f[34]](f[3S]+U+f[3W]+2k+f[2l])};O(3Y==1Q){O(2c==1){1I=1I+f[3X]};O(1w==f[3R]){1w=f[3Q]};O(1w==f[3K]){1w=f[3J]};1I=1I+1w;2c=1;R[f[34]](f[3P]+2o+f[2p]+1w+f[3N])};O(f[2f]2s z){A 1e=z[f[2f]][f[37]]}1J{O(f[2t]2s z){A 1e=z[f[2t]][f[37]]}1J{A 1e=f[6]}};A 2n=/<\\S[^>]*>/g;1e=1e[f[19]](2n,f[6]);O(3g==1Q){O(1e[f[3]]<2m){R[f[34]](f[6]);R[f[34]](1e);R[f[34]](f[6])}1J{R[f[34]](f[6]);1e=1e[f[5]](0,2m);A 2y=1e[f[2Y]](f[8]);1e=1e[f[5]](0,2y);R[f[34]](f[3c]+1e+f[2Z])}};R[f[34]](f[2X]);O(M!=2S-1){R[f[34]](f[6])}};R[f[34]](f[3e])}$(R)[f[2E]](1k(){$(f[2F])[f[2Q]](f[2D],1k(U,1K){1s 1K[f[19]](f[3f],f[3n])})});$(R)[f[2E]](1k(){$(f[2F])[f[2Q]](f[2D],1k(U,1K){1s 1K[f[19]](f[3d],f[3V])})})',62,255,'||||||||||||||x5C|_0x5199|||x65|x74|x61|x22|x7C|x6C|x73|x78|x69|x63||x72|x6E|x62|x6D|x64|x6F|_0xc43ex2|var|x20|x68|x70|x67|x66|x3D|_0xc43ex3|x75|x2F|x3C|x3E|_0xc43ex4|x36|if|x5D|x5B|document||_0xc43ex9|_0xc43ex5|x33|x41|x76|x32|x37|||||||||||x79|x30|_0xc43ex16|x6A|_0xc43ex1f|x2E|x2C|_0xc43ex7|x6B|x43|function|x77|_0xc43exa|x29|x2D|x28|x5F|x34|return|_0xc43exf|x31|x71|_0xc43ex10|_0xc43exd|x44|x45|x42|x49|x35|x24|x39|x7A|_0xc43ex12|for|_0xc43ex17|else|_0xc43ex22|x4D|x4A|61|x46|_0xc43ex1c|true|_0xc43ex8|x4F|x38|_0xc43ex19|x48|x53|x4C|break|x4E|||||||||||_0xc43exb|x7B|_0xc43ex18|74|x7D|48|x50|x54|x3B|x59|_0xc43ex1e|73|numchars|_0xc43ex20|_0xc43ex11|72|while|String|in|84|64|image_tag|removeHtmlTag|x47|_0xc43ex21|parseInt|54|66|_0xc43ex1a|90|95|94|65|55|60|62|63|59|58|56|57|_0xc43ex1b|93|_0xc43ex1d|numposts|x55|x56|new|x57|88|85|87|||||||||||x21|eval|86|96|89|91|showpostsummary|x58|x4B|x51|x52|snippet_count|createSnippet|92|labelthumbs|53|_0xc43ex13|_0xc43ex14|x3A|showpostdate|50|51|52|_0xc43ex15|Array|70|71|x2B|69|68|67|showpostthumbnails|49|catch|200|81|80|300|bp_thumbnail_resize|83|RegExp|82|79|78|75|try|47|97|76|77|showcommentnum|toString|||||||'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is minified code. You can deminify it but you cannot get the original variable names, etc from it.

Comment: It's likely to be uglified code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Uglified Javascript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408535/reverse-uglified-javascript-code)

Comment: It's minified and mangled.

Comment: Your question in unclear. What do you mean by "type of this code"? ECMAScript is not statically typed. As such, code doesn't *have* a "type".

Comment: @Jörg I think you're taking the word "type" in the wrong context here…

Comment: I think he mean the _type_ of encoding used

Comment: thanks for the replies
@JörgWMittag i meant to say what is the encoding used in it

Comment: It looks like ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is obfuscated. You can view a more readable version of it on sites like [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/). Chrome also has a built in beautifier. You still will have to figure out what it does. Also `eval` [can be a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score 0):

It is a minified code that, when executed, redirects you to this web page:
http://www.templatemark.com

Comment: This is basically not true.

Comment: thanks for the answer ! i have a friend who trying to edit his blog and the blog keeps redirecting to this page .. is it possible to edit the code without completely removing it ?

Comment: PROOF: https://jsfiddle.net/kuhmLy20/

Comment: I know the answer looks like a spam but that's basically what this function is doing. Please verify first before saying something isn't true.

Comment: @CEALOA Since the code is minified it was designed to be uneditable manually, unfortunately.

Comment: alright but can i atleast remove the part of the redirection only without removing the whole code and locating this part of the code since it has multiple data ?

Comment: Normally, it would be possible to edit minified codes but the code seems to be obfuscated as well. That means it's deliberately manipulated to be uneditable - refer to the non-minified version of the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/byhf19kw/