# How to get back uglified js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I had an old project that had been uglified using gulp-uglify. I need to work on that project now.

How do I bring it back to normal readable js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Uglified Javascript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408535/reverse-uglified-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "reverse" uglified code. It's a one-way process. The best you can achieve is to beautify the code (indentation and other cosmetic fixes) but you cannot restore the original variable names.